# Paragraph above scrolling enumerate in beamer keeping position

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I have done this before using tricks with absolute positioning of nodes in `tikz`, or more crude by repeating the content manually in slides and using `\phantom`. I would like to know if there is a nice way to do the following:

I have a paragraph  with an enumerate underneath.

```
Blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah,
blah, blah, blah, blah, blah.
 1 Blah
 2 Bleh
 3 Blih
```

such that in the first slide it should appear as

```
Blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah,
blah, blah, blah, blah, blah.
 1 Blah
 2 Bleh
```

and in the next slide as

```
Blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah,
blah, blah, blah, blah, blah.
 3 Blih
```

With the paragraph not changing position, as if the enumerate is scrolling.

Is there a nice way to do this? Nice meaning using some of those instructions already in `beamer` like `\onslide`, `\only`, `\item<2->`, or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option to avoid the "jumping" effect is simply to use an `overlayarea` environment which was designed specifically for these cases. Adjust the width and height according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{4cm}
Some test text for the example test text for the example test text for the example test text for the example test text for the example
\begin{enumerate}
\only<1>{
\item First.
\item Second.}
\only<2>{\item[3.] Third.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

Blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, 
blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah,           
blah, blah, blah,
\begin{enumerate}

\only<1>{%
\item Blah
\item Blah
}  

\only<2>{%
\item[3.] Blah
\item[]
} 
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produce

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it produces the effect? I haven't tried yet, but from reading the code I wonder what happens when the items are not necessarily one line and have different heights.

Comment: I updated my answer with an image of the output.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy it works in some cases, but will fail, for exmaple, if the text for the second `\item` spans more than one line, as in `\only<1>{
\item Blah
\item Blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, 
blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah,           
blah, blah, blah,
}`